# What package contains the CAA_File library?

Tags: codesys

And where do I obtain the package from? I would imagine it comes from some package on the CoDeSys store but I can't seem to find which one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

1. Open library manager
2. Click add library,
3. Click advanced
4. Browse to Intern -> CAA -> System -> CAA File
5. Select the CAA file and hit OK

Then you can find the library under FILE namespace.